# Navigate Webbrowser from another Class C#

Tags: c#, class, debugging, controls

I am trying to navigate a webbrowser1 from another class called Class.cs and the webbrowser1 is in Form1. When I debug and begin to navigate, I have button one call the class, the class then navigates, problem is that my mouse shows the webbrowser loads and the code goes through but the actual webbrowser stays on the same page and does not navigate. How can I properly control a webbrowser navigation from another class when calling the class from a button on Form1?

this is from the class

```
public async void Search()
    {

        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        //form1 = new bis.Form1();

        form1.webBrowser1.Navigate("google.com");
        form1.webBrowser2.Navigate("facebook.com");
```

and this is from form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Biz.Search();
```

Comment: Can you show us a code snippet for how you call your navigate method?

Comment: Just added it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are instantiating another instance of your form inside your Search method different than the one displayed on your screen, you should use the same​ instance, you may send it as a parameter to your method.

```
public async void Search(Form yourForm)
{ 
    yourForm.webBrowser1.Navigate("google.com");
    yourForm.webBrowser2.Navigate("facebook.com");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Biz.Search(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example please.

Comment: This Works Great, did (Form1 form1) Thank you so much.